# Prove that if $\int_a^b f(x)^p dx = 0$, then $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$ for $p > 1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ with $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Prove that if $\int_a^b f(x)^p dx = 0$, then $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$ for $p > 1$. I was thinking of bounding $f$ by $f(x)^p$ with a constant, but I'm not sure how to deal with the x-values when $f(x)$ approach $0$.

Comment: Are the integrals written correctly?

Comment: yes, with f^p implying f

Comment: Is this for all $p>1$ or for some $p>1$?

Comment: It should be for all, I think.

Comment: If $f^p\geq 0$ is also continuous and the above conditions satisfy then $f^p=0\forall x\in [a,b]$, so $f=0$ as $p>1$ otherwise $f^p$ has countably many discontinuites in which case we can break the interval s.t. in each interval it is continuous and apply the same argument.

Comment: @PNDas A Riemann integrable function can have uncoutably many discontnuities.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thank you for the comment but can you give such an example.

Comment: A bounded functiion is Riemann integrable **if and only if** it is continuous almost everywhere.  A set of measure $0$ can be uncountable: eg Cantor set.  @PNDas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. if $f(x) \geq \epsilon$ then $f(x)\leq \epsilon^{1-p} f(x)^{p}$. In any case $f(x) \leq \epsilon + \epsilon^{1-p} f(x)^{p}$. Hence $\int f(x)dx \leq \epsilon^{1-p}\int f^{p}(x)dx+\epsilon$ this gives $\int f(x)dx \leq \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this gives $\int f(x)dx=0$.